# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, json, jsondecoder

i am a little bit new to coding, but i am trying to get data stored in a json file by another script though it keeps on giving me errors 
 This is my code

```
import requests

URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict"
TEST_AUDIO_FILE_PATH = "test/soma.wav"

if __name__ =="__main__":
    audio_file = open(TEST_AUDIO_FILE_PATH, "rb")
    values = {"file":(TEST_AUDIO_FILE_PATH, audio_file, "audio/wav")}
    response = requests.post(URL, files=values)
    data = response.json()

    print(f"Predicted keyword is: {data['keyword']}")
```

This is the error i keep on getting
    File "C:\Users\Tatooine\Desktop\FYP\client.py", line 11, in 
    response.json()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Answer (score 0):

i think you should decode the **data** variable first 
`data = response.decode()`

then after you can convert it to a json object

```
import json 
data = json.loads(data)
```

then print

```
print(f"Predicted keyword is: {data['keyword']}")
```

please let me know, if this works for you

Comment: i had tried this  but it gives me an, AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'decode'